# Water colour changes to yellow after electrolysis

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

A salesman recently conducted electrolysis experiment on 4 samples of water-- river water,tap water, his own water and water from Aquaguard RO filter. The colour change after electrolysis on different samples of water is given in the pic given below? Is tap water ,river water and Aquaguard RO water can be consumed for drinking purposes?[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is pure scam! All he is doing is using an electrode which is corroding during electrolysis. The flocculated material you see in tap water is just a metallic hydroxide. If tap water had this much of metals, nobody will survive. Such a fraudulent salesman should be shooed away!

Comment: What can be the possible explanation why aquagyard RO water changes yellow in colour?

Comment: corroding electrodes. Most likely he used iron anodes with some traces of salt. He is using different metallic anodes, hence different colors.

Comment: He used the same electrodes in the whole process.

Comment: Was he adding anything? Most likely it is an iron electrode.

Comment: It suffices that the same inert el. is placed deeper to bring a metallic part in contact to the water... I agree with this, likely iron. Note the different colour in tap water, meaning tap water is chlorinated. Just I disagree with the fact that water from which things can be precipitate or flocculated must necessarily kill.